# Redis client for Angular applications

Tags: javascript, angular, logging, redis, elastic-stack

We use [Redis](https://redis.io/) as buffer for our ELK log-stack. Now I want to send the logs of an Angular 6 application to the buffer so that I can analyze them but I cannot find any clients for angular or any similar framework that would do the job.

Does anyone know how I can send the logs of an angular app to a Redis buffer?

Comment: Angular is client side. You don't want client side apps connecting directly to redis, you need some intermediate server to handle the data.